# Why do I get compile error message for the last for next loop?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, compiler-errors, multiple-columns

```
Sub Step2()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim ncol As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Detailed Sample Report")

    ws.Range("A1:D11").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A1:K4"))

    ncol = Sheets("owssvr").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox (ncol)

    ws.Range("A1:A11").Copy

    For i = 1 To ncol
        NextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws.Range("A" & NextRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Next

    For j = 2 To ncol
        Sheets("owssvr").Range("B" &j& ":B" & j+10).Value =WorksheetFunction.Transpose.Range("A" &j+1 ":K" &j+1)
        j = j + 12

End Sub
```

Comment: Because your `For j = 2 To ncol` loop has no `Next j`? And because your `&j&` has not the correct spacing `& j &` and same for `&j+1` that must be `& j + 1`. Also don't mess with the counter of your loop `j = j + 12` it will increase automatically at a `Next j` statement. If you need to increase it more than `+1` each iteration ther use something like `For j = 2 To ncol Step 12` or a `Do` loop where you can iterate manually.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This resolved my problem.